# How to construct an API for a list of events, to be updated in the future

Tags: android, ios, list

I'm constructing an API which is going to be used by an Android and an iPhone app. The app gets a list of events which can regularly be updated. There are currently two ideas.

1. Creating it using pagination so that it first loads the first 10 events to load results on the screen, and when the user scrolls further it should load more events. I then regularly poll the API to see if there are any new events.
2. First get the paginated list of id's of events (also first 10), after which the apps should get the full event details in separate threads using one call for every event. In that way it can load all events simultaneously which supposedly makes it faster.

I tend to lean more towards the first solution because it's more simple, but somebody else said the second is a way better idea. I have the idea that the separate threads only add complexity to the case and don't increase the speed significantly. I know that the best way to know is to test it, but building both and testing it takes a lot of time. I therefore wonder whether there are any best practices in getting a continuously updated list of events from an API.

So; which of the two do you think would be best and why?

Comment: use APS, apple push services instead of polling .

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the amount of data your events contain. If each event description is **only a few fields** don't bother to load each event in a separate thread, the overhead will kill any possible performance gain - just get all data in the get events request.

If it is a lot of data per event description, you can argue whether you really want to preload all event descriptions before the user selects an event - probably the user will never click on any of the events, then you did load the data for nothing.

That said, it is also not a bad idea to prepare your API to enable both: Get a list of short event descriptions and a call to get event details for a certain event (or a list of event ids), or get a list which contains the full event descriptions.

Comment: Thanks, I think we're indeed going for a `getAllEvents` and `getEventDetails` call. Thanks for your thoughts!